# Unable to get automatic-instrumentation with Spring boot and otel-collector working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, open-telemetry, spring-cloud-sleuth

I had created a Spring-boot micro-service using spring-cloud-sleuth for distributed-tracing. I had a otel-collector which was receiving logs and traces from the application and it was exporting it to Datadog. The flow was working properly.

However, starting from Spring-boot 3.0.5, support of sleuth is removed and observability has been split into two parts some in Spring-boot itself and some part in micrometer. I upgraded my spring-boot version and made changes to export traces to otel-collector but I am not able to get it working. I enabled the Spring debug logs and I can see that the bean for [OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/tracing/OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.java) is being created. Can someone help me understand if I am doing anything wrong? I am posting the debug logs related to class OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration below. The messages indicate all the beans in this class are properly loaded. I am expecting an error saying unable to connect at some IP and port but getting nothing

```
OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'io.micrometer.tracing.otel.bridge.OtelTracer', 'io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.SdkTracerProvider', 'io.opentelemetry.api.OpenTelemetry' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (management.tracing.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#micrometerOtelTracer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#openTelemetry matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.opentelemetry.api.OpenTelemetry; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#otelContextPropagators matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.opentelemetry.context.propagation.ContextPropagators; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#otelCurrentTraceContext matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.micrometer.tracing.otel.bridge.OtelCurrentTraceContext; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#otelPropagator matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.micrometer.tracing.otel.bridge.OtelPropagator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#otelSampler matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.samplers.Sampler; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#otelSdkTracerProvider matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.SdkTracerProvider; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#otelSlf4JEventListener matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.micrometer.tracing.otel.bridge.Slf4JEventListener; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#otelSpanCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.micrometer.tracing.SpanCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#otelTracer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Tracer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration#otelTracerEventPublisher matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.micrometer.tracing.otel.bridge.OtelTracer$EventPublisher; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.BaggageConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (management.tracing.baggage.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.BaggageConfiguration#otelSlf4JBaggageEventListener matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (management.tracing.baggage.correlation.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: io.micrometer.tracing.otel.bridge.Slf4JBaggageEventListener; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.BaggageConfiguration#w3cTextMapPropagatorWithBaggage matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (management.tracing.propagation.type=W3C) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
```